# Stochastic integral is progressive

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

If I want to show that a stochastic integral, namely $$Y_t=\int_0^t\phi_s dB_s$$ where B is the standard Brownian motion, is progressive, is it enough to show that the integrand $\phi_s$ it is progressive? Could you provide some comments?

Comment: What do you mean by "enough to show that the integrand is progressive"? You need some assumptions which ensure that the integral exists (typically you **assume** that $\phi$ is progressive).

Comment: @saz yes, that's true, so if I know that $\phi$ is progressive than also $Y_t$ it is?